# Filters that interact together in Leaflet

Tags: javascript, filter, leaflet

I'm trying to figure out how to create filters in Leaflet that interact together, meaning that the behavior of a filter depends on which other filters are activated.

I explain myself with an example. I want to display restaurants on a map and add filters that depend on several restaurants' attributes as type/price/grade/... . At the end, what I would like to achieve is when the user clicks on the filter "Burger type", then all the Burger restaurants are displayed on the map, when the user activates the "Burger type" filter and the "below 10$ price" filter, then all the Burger restaurant below 10$ are displayed, and when the user removes the "Burger type" filter and keep the "below 10$ price" filter, then all the restaurants that cost less that 10$ must be displayed.

This is a short list of my listRestaurants.json data I'm using:

```js
allRestaurants = [
  {
    "Type": "Burger",
    "Name": "231 East Street",
    "URL": "http://www.231-east.fr/",
    "Grade": 4,
    "Price": 7,
    "lat": 48.8753906,
    "lng": 2.323661500000071
  },
  {
    "Type": "Burger",
    "Name": "HAND",
    "URL": "https://www.tripadvisor.fr/Restaurant_Review-g187147-d2514552-Reviews-H_A_N_D-Paris_Ile_de_France.html",
    "Grade": 2,
    "Price": 12,
    "lat": 48.86592889999999,
    "lng": 2.3363045999999486
  },
  {
    "Type": "Italian",
    "Name": "La Piazzetta",
    "URL": "https://www.facebook.com/La-Piazzetta-892439337443373/",
    "Grade": 7,
    "Price": 8,
    "lat": 48.8672245,
    "lng": 2.3442474999999376
  },
```

Therefore, when the "Burger type" filter is activated, the two burger restaurants "231 East Street" and "HAND" must be displayed on the map;
when the "Burger type" and the "below 10$ price" filters are activated, only the Burger restaurant "231 East Street" must be displayed on the map;
when only the "below 10$ price" filter is activated, the burger restaurant "231 East Street" and the Italian restaurant "La Piazzetta" must be displayed on the map.

I have read the Leaflet tutorial on Layers control http://leafletjs.com/examples/layers-control.html, so I'm aware of how creating a filter based on one attribute, for example the type of restaurants. Here is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Restaurants filters</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet/v0.7.7/leaflet.css" />
    <script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet/v0.7.7/leaflet.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map" style="height: 800px;"></div>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='listRestaurants.json'></script>

    <script>
      // map
      var map = L.map( 'map', {
        center: [48.87, 2.33],
        minZoom: 2,
        zoom: 15
      });

      L.tileLayer( 'http://{s}.mqcdn.com/tiles/1.0.0/map/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright" title="OpenStreetMap" target="_blank">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors | Tiles Courtesy of <a href="http://www.mapquest.com/" title="MapQuest" target="_blank">MapQuest</a> <img src="http://developer.mapquest.com/content/osm/mq_logo.png" width="16" height="16">',
        subdomains: ['otile1','otile2','otile3','otile4']
      }).addTo( map );

      // Type groups creation
      var burger = []
      var italian = []
      for ( var i=0; i < allRestaurants.length; ++i ) 
      {
        if (allRestaurants[i].Type && allRestaurants[i].Type=="Burger") {
          var a = new L.marker( [allRestaurants[i].lat, allRestaurants[i].lng]);
          burger.push(a)
        }
        if (allRestaurants[i].Type && allRestaurants[i].Type=="Italian") {
          var a = L.marker( [allRestaurants[i].lat, allRestaurants[i].lng]);
          italian.push(a)
        }
      }

      // Filters creation
      var Burger = L.layerGroup(burger);
      var Italian = L.layerGroup(italian);

      var overlayMaps = {
        "Burger": Burger,
        "Italian": Italian

      };

      L.control.layers(null,overlayMaps).addTo(map);

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

However I have no clue of how creating new filters such as "Price" filters that would interact with the "Type" filter I've already have.

Hope my question is clear. Examples would be much appreciated. Thx

Answer (score 0):

Did you check this puglin?
https://github.com/perliedman/leaflet-underneath

demo:
http://dev.cartocite.fr/CultureNantes/

or

https://github.com/utahemre/Leaflet.GeoJSONAutocomplete

demo:
https://utahemre.github.io/geojsontest.html